# Can't express variables from the system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, algebra-precalculus

It a homework task

Can it be transformed to the system, where each expression of N doesn't depend on another N(like $N1=$some stuff that doesn't contain any N):

$$N_3=\dfrac{-pB_{13}N_1}{-A_{31}-pB_{32}-A_{32}}$$
$$N_2=\dfrac{(pB_{32}+A_{32})N_3}{A_{21}}$$
$$N_1=\dfrac{A_{31}N_3+A_{21}N_2}{pB_{13}}$$

Consider $p$, $B_{32}$, $B_{13}$, $A_{32}$, $A_{21}$, $A_{31}$, (shortly all B and A and p) as a constant

Now I clarify, that I want to transform the system above to system

$$N_3=stuff\space without\space any\space N$$
$$N_2=stuff\space without\space any\space N$$
$$N_1=stuff\space without\space any\space N$$

I don't really need a complete solution, just answer is it possible or, because my math skills are not pro, and I am getting $N_1+N_1(some\space stuff)=0$

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we plug the second into the third, then the first into the third we eliminate $N_2$ and $N_3$

$$N_1=\dfrac{A_{31}N_3+A_{21}N_2}{pB_{13}}\\
N_1=\dfrac{A_{31}N_3+(pB_{32}+A_{32})N_3}{pB_{13}}\\
N_1=\dfrac{A_{31}+(pB_{32}+A_{32})}{pB_{13}}N_3\\
N_1=\dfrac{A_{31}+(pB_{32}+A_{32})}{pB_{13}}\dfrac{-pB_{13}N_1}{-A_{31}-pB_{32}-A_{32}}$$
Now note that the $N_1$s divide out so your system is singular.  If what is multiplying $N_1$ on the right is equal to $1$ or $0$ you can choose $N_1$ at will.  Otherwise the equations are inconsistent.

Comment: Sooo, I cant get system like $N_3=stuff-witout-N; N_2=stuff-witout-N; N_1=stuff-without-N$?

Comment: No, you only have two equations in three unknowns as Gribouillis shows.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assume $p B_{1 3} \neq 0$ otherwise the last equation is meaningless. This last equation is then a consequence of the two first equations. Hence it can be removed. $N_1$ can take any value, the first equation gives $N_3$ and the second equation then gives $N_2$.

You cannot transform the system the way you want because this system doesn't have a unique solution. There is an arbitrary parameter in the solution. You can write it for example as
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{}
 N_1 = k\cr
N_2 = x k\cr
N_3 = y k
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $k$ is arbitrary. If you need only one solution, choose all the $N_i=0$

Comment: I don't really need to solve it, instead I need to transform it to the system where each N doesn't depen on any N(including itself)

Comment: Thank You for response